# Persisting date vales into mySql database via Apache POI

Tags: java, mysql, date, jpa, apache-poi

I am using Apache POI to read in an excel dataset and JPA to persist into the database. This is working fine except for the fact i need to get a set of date/time values correctly into the database using the same method (read in with apache poi, then persist into the database). At the moment i am using   SimpleDateFormat which is not of any use really. We need to query this column so i need to have to use mySQL dates ideally in the database.

**Dataset example of time/date column**

21/10/2012 13:20:00

**Java**

```
     Sheet sheet1 = wb.getSheetAt(0);

        String dateTimeFormat = "dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss";
        SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat(dateTimeFormat);


        for (int i = 1; i <= sheet1 .getLastRowNum(); i++) {

            row = sheet1 .getRow(i);
            String sheet1Id = i+"";

            double excelDateTime = row.getCell(0).getNumericCellValue();
            Date javaDateTime=HSSFDateUtil.getJavaDate(excelDateTime,false);
            String dateTime = dateFormat.format(javaDateTime);

            Table1 sheet1=new Table1 (sheet1Id ,dateTime)
            addToDatabase(table1); 

        }
```

Any solutions to this and any advice as to the best way to create this column in the mySQL database aswell(The column is a varchar at present)?

Cheers

Comment: Why are you using `VARCHAR` and not something sensible like `DATETIME` or `TIMESTAMP`?

Comment: I was using varchar up until now - just to get it working in string format - im just learning sql in the past few weeks, Is TIMSTAMP the type i should use?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When using JPA/JDBC, a java.util.Date corresponds to a DATETIME column (or TIMESTAMP, or DATE, see the [MySQL-manual](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/datetime.html) to learn about their subtle differences). Since you already get a Date object directly from `HSSFDateUtil`, you don't need any further conversion.

PS: Why don't you use [`HSSFCell.getDateCellValue()`](http://poi.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/poi/hssf/usermodel/HSSFCell.html#getDateCellValue%28%29) directly?

Comment: Thanks, Yes this is what i have at the moment - it is not displaying in mySql in the format i wanted but i dont think that is a problem as i can edit the way the data looks on my GUI front end. The important thing is that queries can be executed correctly, Cheers.